# Alternative to ResourceBundleViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a legacy jsp application with views.properties file, from which I use `ResourceBundleViewResolver` to load all the views. As `ResourceBundleViewResolver` has been deprecated from Spring 5.3,  I have checked the spring documentation and it says "as of 5.3, in favor of Spring's common view resolver variants and/or custom resolver implementations". I would like to know the alternative to use the BundleViewResolver. Apologies in advance, I am very new to dealing with legacy applications.

Edit

Config.java

```
public class Configuration_place extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ResourceBundleViewResolver viewResolver(){
ResourceBundleViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
tilesViewResolver.setBasename("views");
return tilesViewResolver;
}

@Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions("/tiles-def.xml");
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }
```

views.properties

```
index.(class) = org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
index.url = index

login.(class) = org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
login.url = login
```

tiles-def.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
"http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3.0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
<definition name = "master.page" template = "/views/templates/layout_main.jsp">
<put-attribute name = "title" value = "JSP Application" />
<put-attribute name = "header" value = "/views/templates/header.jsp" />
<put-attribute name = "menu" value = "/views/templates/menubar.jsp" />
<put-attribute name = "error" value = "/views/templates/errorMessage.jsp" />
<put-attribute name = "content" value = "" />
<put-attribute name = "footer" value = "/views/templates/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name = "index" extends="master.page">
<put-attribute name="content" value="/views/intro.jsp" />

</definition>

<definition name = "login" extends="master.page">
<put-attribute name="content" value="/views/login.jsp" />
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: Replace the configuration with an `@Configuration` class and use an `@BeanNameViewResolver` instead.

Comment: Also do you really need the `ResourceBundleViewResolver` if so why? Why wouldn't this be possible with the regular `InternalResourceViewResolver` (as you indicate you are using JSP).

Comment: I've tried with the InternalResourceViewResolver, and have provided the web-inf path but it fails to fetch the jsp pages. When I use the ResourceBundleViewResolver with views.properties, the application works as intended.

Comment: Without knowing what is in your specific configuration file this will be impossible to answer. You are either specifying the wrong configuration in the `InternalResourceViewResolver` or you are doing very weird things in the configuration (and thus should replace all that config with `@Bean` declarations for `View` instances, which is what the `ResourceBundleViewResolver` does as well).

Comment: I've added the sample code of my application and currently the project structure does not contain WEB-INF and the folders of the pages are in the webapp folder located as  [src->main->webapp]

Comment: You are using tiles so you should be using the [`TilesViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles3/TilesViewResolver.html) instead of the `InternalViewResolver`.